# OCRGoogle API Key not successful

Tags: g1ant

I have created an API key for the Google Cloud Vision, but it is still asking for the same.

I have attached a link to this post, this link consists of the error message that I have got after I ran the G1ANT Program and the credential details of my API.

[image]

Showing error dialog reading:

> You must provide ApiKey or JsonCredential argument to log in to the Google Cloud Service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please type chrome or any web browser text after ocrgoogle.login
Followed by api [key]
Here Is a sample:-
ocrgoogle.login chrome apikey AIzaSyDyESzAAAD9r1deIrC7eP8v6IipoJXBWFQ